# How do bcprov and bcprov-ext differ?

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I noticed that there are two bouncycastle provider libraries for Java; *bcprov* and *bcprov-ext*.  How do they differ?  How do I choose which to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*bcprov* is typically the library you want.

*bcprov-ext* includes some obscure crypto algorithms that haven't been part of the main release since v1.4.0.

This is briefly explained on the  [latest releases page](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html):

> From release 1.40 some implementations of encryption algorithms were removed from the regular jar files at the request of a number of users. Jars with names of the form **`*-ext-*`** still include these (at the moment the list is: NTRU).

NTRU seems to be [this algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRU). Personally I'd never heard of it before...